# Update property used in a tableView from another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, properties

I have `FirstViewController` and `SecondTableViewController`. In `SecondTableViewController.m`, I create a cell in the `cellForRow...` method where the `cell.textLabel.text` is a string from an NSInteger property ("`count`") of the `SecondTableViewController`.

I would like a button in `FirstViewController` to increment the value of `count`.

I've tried making a property of `FirstViewController` and then using that:

```
@property SecondTableViewController *viewController;
```

and

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    self.viewController.count++;
    [self.viewController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But this way isn't working. `count` is still its original value of zero. I've also reloaded the table in `viewWillAppear` and still nothing. How can I do this?

Comment: The normal pattern is that first vc and second vc share access to your app's model.  The model can have a count property that first vc increments and second vc reads.

Comment: You probably want to be doing this with delegates instead, rather than retaining instances of view controllers that are likely to be destroyed.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the idea better now but how can this be done with delegates?

Answer (score 0):

Count being used as a property may be where you are going wrong because count is a method that returns the number of objects in an array that is found in foundation framework. Also keep in mind that if you are storing a integer into a string object try storing it in this format.

```
cell.textlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", count];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: viewControllers are not arrays, and therefore do not natively have that property 'count'. Agreed it should be named unambiguously, but that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

[image: Its the <code>FirstViewController</code>, in which I had passed only one object reference of <code>SecondTableViewController</code>][image: Its the <code>SecondTableViewController</code> in which you only need to implement <code>viewWillAppear</code> method and reload the table]

Check out those two images and implement the similar logic and get the solution.

**----- END OF NEW EDIT -----**

**OLD**

I think you haven't assigned and allocated memory for `SecondTableViewController` reference i.e, `self.viewController` of `FirstViewController` in its `viewDidLoad` method i.e,

```
-(void) viewDidLoad //In FirstViewController
{
    self.viewController = [[SecondTableViewController alloc] init];
}
```

and pushed the same reference on to the stack of `navigationController` after performing button taps to increase the count of `count` variable of `SecondTableViewController`.

If you are not clear, comment.

Comment: I did allocate the memory but the same problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
firstViewController.h

@interface DMFirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) DMSecondViewController * secondController;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end



firstViewController.m

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    ++self.secondController.count;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondController animated:YES];

}


secondViewController.h

@property (nonatomic) int count;


secondViewController.m

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     NSLog(@"%d", self.count);


}
```